# Create widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, design-patterns, widget, flutter-animation

I'm trying to create this widget here

[image]

This is the result I got, I'm having trouble limiting the size of the widget without decreasing the text

[image]

```
SizedBox(
  height: 90,
  width: double.infinity,
  child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: 10,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 15),
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
      return Container(
        height: 80,
        width: 78,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 11),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: OutlinedButton(
          onPressed: () {

          },
          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.cyan, width: 1),

          ),
          child: const Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("SEG", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 10 )),
              Text("20", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 10 )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    },

  ),
)
```

Comment: ur image isn't working

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure out what your problem really is, **but there's no relation between the text size and the size of the widget which contains the text.**

text size is applied based on what you have already set, if not, the default is applied.

and btw, you are setting a padding for the `Container`'s child : `padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 11)`.

you have made it work look like a margin, it's ok, but recommended to use margin property instead.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the code you provided, Now you can get the result you are expecting.

```
SizedBox(
          height: 90,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 10,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0, horizontal: 15),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                height: 80,
                width: 78,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: OutlinedButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                    side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.cyan, width: 1),
                  ),
                  child: const Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text("SEG",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16)),
                      Text("20",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```